# Append text after ID in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a template, which has code, currently saying:

```
<a href="{% url 'vote-time-series' record.id %}">Vote time series</a>
```

I want it to generate URLs matching:

```
path('vote-records/<int:pk>/time-series', vote_time_series, name='vote-time-series')
```

The solution linked in earlier pages only works with straight appending. How do I do this, where the ID is put in the middle?

Comment: What URL do you get in the template currently?

Comment: What do you mean with that? You mean the thing generated? It gives a `NoReverseMatch`

Comment: <a href="/vote-records/{{ record.id }}/time-series/">Vote time series</a>

Comment: if your question about generate url in urls.py, try create : `url(r'^vote-records/(?P<pk>\w+)/time-series/$', def_of_view_py, name='vote-time-series')` inside `urlpatterns`

Comment: That's the wrong version of Django

Comment: @WayBehind, that works, but isn't half the point of this thing not to hard code stuff?

Comment: Perhaps. I usually hard code most of my links other than `static` as I want to make sure my links are correct. Maybe not the Django way, but it works for me. Here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the url wirh args

```
{% url 'vote-time-series' pk=record.id %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url